# Vue-i18n 'Cannot read property '_t' of undefined at Proxy.Vue.$t'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-i18n

Having issues incorporating vue-i18n into my app. Used [this page](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-add-internationalization-to-a-vue-application-d9cfdcabb03b) as inspiration.

```
  <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto" >
    <b-nav-item-dropdown :text="display_name" right>
      <b-dropdown-item disabled>{{ $t('username') }}: {{ username }}</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item disabled>Organisation: {{ organisation }}</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>
  </b-navbar-nav>
```

Gives the error: `Cannot read property '_t' of undefined at Proxy.Vue.$t`
Tracking the error in Chrome devtools takes me to line 149 (the return statement) of vue-i18n.esm.js:

```
Vue.prototype.$t = function (key) {
  var values = [], len = arguments.length - 1;
  while ( len-- > 0 ) values[ len ] = arguments[ len + 1 ];

  var i18n = this.$i18n;
  return i18n._t.apply(i18n, [ key, i18n.locale, i18n._getMessages(), this ].concat( values ))
};
```

I'm using vue-cli-3 webpack config and installed vue-i18n from npm and using as a plugin.

i18n.js (in src/plugins directory):

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

const messages = {
  'en': {
    username: 'Username',
    ...
  },
  'se': {
    username: 'Användarnamn',
    ...
  }
};

export let i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en', // set locale
  fallbackLocale: 'se', // set fallback locale
  messages, // set locale messages
});
```

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import VueSpinners from 'vue-spinners'

import i18n from './plugins/i18n'
...
new Vue({
  router,
  i18n,
  data() {
    return store;
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Dependencies from package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
  "npm": "^6.5.0",
  "ol": "^5.3.0",
  "proj4": "^2.5.0",
  "qs": "^6.6.0",
  "vue": "^2.5.17",
  "vue-i18n": "^8.8.1",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
  "vue-spinners": "^1.0.2"
},
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: If anyone came to this page from trying to get i18n to work with component testing in Cypress there is an example in their old repository that goes through it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/e49f1d31fa36b8e78fe61d5e98ec26859f64e381/npm/vue/cypress/component/advanced/i18n/spec.js)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ah, embarrassingly simple, I changed

`import i18n from './plugins/i18n'`

to

`import {i18n} from './plugins/i18n'`

and all works now.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone came here with the same issue, but is using `export default`, I had this in my main.js:

```
import translations from './translations';

new Vue({
    translations,
    ...
}).$mount('#app');
```

Where translations/index.js loaded the plugin and everything like normal. Apparently you have to name the import 'i18n' for this to work correctly:

```
import i18n from './translations';

new Vue({
    i18n,
    ...
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: You can name the import whatever you like, but you can only use the ES6 notation for assigning it to an object property if you name it `i18n`

Answer (score 2):

> src/i18n/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)


// 注册i18n实例并引入语言文件
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'zh_cn',
  messages: {
    'zh_cn': require('@/assets/languages/zh_cn.json'),
    'en_us': require('@/assets/languages/en_us.json'),
    'es_ve': require('@/assets/languages/es-ve.json')
  }
})

export default i18n
```

> main.js

```
import i18n from '@/i18n'

new Vue({
  i18n,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2):

***Vue.prototype._i18n = i18n*** must be under the line ***App.mpType = 'app'***

```js
App.mpType = 'app'
Vue.prototype._i18n = i18n
```

https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/276#issuecomment-663071363

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had same problem, but my problem wasn't because of import syntax.
I'll say my solution so hope it helps someone.
At first I had installed vue-i18n by npm which I got this problem so
I have solved my problem by removing vue-i18n package and installing vue-i18n by vue cli: 
`vue add i18n`

https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/installation.html#compatibility-note

By installing in this way, vue cli add some config in vue config and these configs solved my problem which I couldn't find answer for it from anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I also reported this error, but I did not solve it by using the above method. In the end, I found that we should not introduce modal.  Remove the following code to resolve:

```
import Modal from XXX

export default {
  components: {
    Modal
}
```