# ypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using laravel + vue to build my site, I'm using vue18n for localization.
my app.js file is:

```
 require('./bootstrap');
 window.Vue = require('vue');
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import App from './components/App.vue';
 import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
 import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { routes } from './routes';
 import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

 import "bootstrap";
 import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
 
 Vue.use(VueI18n);
 Vue.use(VueRouter);
 Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

 const router = new VueRouter({
     mode: 'history',
     routes: routes
 });

 const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     router: router,
     render: h => h(App),
 });
```

in my newarticle.vue:

```
<p>{{$t('message')}}</p>
```

and I created a folder (locales) , in this folder I have two files (en.json) and (ar.json).

but this problem appear:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_t' of undefined
at Proxy.Vue.$t (app.js:37834)
at Proxy.render (app.js:40051)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (app.js:47261)
at VueComponent.updateComponent (app.js:47779)
at Watcher.get (app.js:48192)
at new Watcher (app.js:48181)
at mountComponent (app.js:47786)
at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:52763)
at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (app.js:55672)
at init (app.js:46834)
```

can you help me, please

Comment: hm you could check the compiled `app.js` file at that line and see if you can trace it back to the source code

Comment: If you remove the line of ```<p>{{$t('message')}}</p>``` is the error disappearing?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes but i need it , I cant remove it

Comment: @Flame can you explain more for me ,please

Comment: Jad, I do not want you to remove it permanently. The question seeks to find out whether that line is the cause indeed of your issue. You need to remove the line for a minute and test. If the error still comes, then something else is causing it. If the error no longer comes, then we confirmed that this is the problematic line.

Comment: @LajosArpad ,ok sorry i did that and the error no longer comes

Comment: Is this link helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666293/vue-i18n-cannot-read-property-t-of-undefined-at-proxy-vue-t

?

Comment: @LajosArpad thank you but I can't find my answer in this link, Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Have you looked at the accepted answer? For someone having a similar behavior the solution was to destructure the import.

Comment: @LajosArpad  thank you, The problem is I have to manually create and embed the i10n.js file.

Comment: Can you destructure it?

Comment: I can't understand you can you explain